# Is my proof about the compact operator right?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I have tried to solve this problem. Please let me know if I need to do more. Of course, I know that there are some alternate way to prove the following operator is compact.

Let
$T:L^{2}(0,1)\to L^{2}(0,1)$
be the linear operator defined by

$$ T(u)(x)=\int_{0}^{x}u(t)dt\;\; \forall x\in(0,1). $$ 
Prove that 
$T$ 
is compact.

Proof:
Since 
$L^{2}(0,1)$
is a separable Hilbert space so we will prove that if 
$u_{n}\to 0\; weakly$
then 
$\Vert Tu_{n}\Vert\to 0 $
in norm. So assume that 
$u_{n}\to 0\; weakly$
then

$$\Vert Tu_{n}\Vert_{2}=(\int_{0}^{1}\vert \int_{0}^{x}u_{n}(t)dt \vert^{2} dx)^{1/2} $$
by the Minkowskis’inequality for integrals,
$$ \leq\int_{0}^{x}(\int_{0}^{1}\vert u_{n}(t)\vert^{2}dx)^{1/2}dt=\int_{0}^{x} \vert u_{n}(t)\vert dt$$
Now, since 
$u_{n}\to 0\; weakly$
in 
$L^{2}(0,1),$
then

$$\int_{0}^{x} \vert u_{n}(t)\vert dt\to 0. $$
Therefore, 
$$\Vert Tu_{n}\Vert_{2}\to 0. $$

Comment: How do you use the Minkowskis' inequality ? I ask because I see that $x$ is a variable in integral

Comment: It is not true in general that $\int_0^x |u_n (t)| dt \to 0$ if $u_n \to 0$ weakly in $L^2$. As a counterexample, consider $u_n (t) = e^{2\pi  i n t} 1_{[0,1]} (t)$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. How can I repair the proof?

Comment: @Youem we can replace $x=1$ even if it is not true. But I don't see any problem with it.